# Can't get my "code" validated by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, client-side-validation

Okay, so for my school project I need to create a page that has a form to input a contest code in a certain format, use javascript to validate it and display a "sorry" message. I believe I have everything correct, but clearly I do not as I am here asking for help. It seems like every time I try to submit the code, the page just refreshes, and my JSFiddle test returns a wonky error. Any help would be appreciated. The code that I am using is below with two JSFiddle links, one with just my code, and one with all of my HTML and my JavaScripting:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.code_input').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('.code', this).val().match(/^[0-9]{6}\-[0-9]{6}\-[a-z]$/)) {
        alert('Sorry, you did not win.');
    }else{
        alert('Not a valid code. Please try again.')
    }
}); // reference point
</script>

<section class="code_input">
  <form method="post">
    <input type="text" class="code" name="code" placeholder="Type Code Here" />
    <input id="submit" type='submit' value='Check Number'>
  </form>
</section>
```

[JSFiddle - Just the code](https://jsfiddle.net/dark_nemesis/zpho07gc/)
[JSFiddle - All the code](https://jsfiddle.net/dark_nemesis/hw031twu/)

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: What does java have to do with it ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I'm still rather new to JavaScripting, and still use Java and JavaScript interchangeably. I've edited/fixed the title.

Comment: Well, *stop that*, because they are entirely different languages, having very little in common.

Comment: @Andreas Will do. Just a bad habit that I am clearly finding hard to break.

Comment: delete '''e.preventDefault();''' or move it in statement where code not valid. And why do you use jQuery? You can easily solve this task with native js.

Comment: @dark_nemesis  https://jsfiddle.net/hw031twu/1/ full code jquery library link problem

Comment: @SarkisArutiunian removing `e.preventDefault();` would simply make the page refresh when you clicked the button without even calling the OPs validation code

Comment: @dark_nemesis to clarify what prasad said, you cannot use HTML tags in the JavaScript window on jsFiddle. You need to click the "Javascript" button in the windows top right or use "external resources" in the left sidebar to load jquery and other libraries. If you open the console, you will see quite a few errors displayed due to the html being there.

Comment: @SarkisArutiunian I don't understand why people ask non-sense which has nothing to do with the issue at hand like, Why are you using jQuery? Who cares, just answer the question or go away

Comment: answer is below, and this is  stackoverflow, so if you ask question be ready get answer and some additional advices, for example not using additional libraries in cases where you can avoid it. But if you want just get answer or someone will do work for you, you free to go find someone on free-lance and pay for it.

Comment: @SarkisArutiunian I have JQuery on there because I actually recycled this page from a previous project. I thought it would be easier to reuse it since it had a previous form on it, and already contained some validation script on it. Clearly I was wrong about that though as I've deleted all of the scripting on it, and am learning that it's easier to just start from scratch. As for the additional advise, I welcome it with open arms. It can only help me to understand that which I am doing wrong, and in the long run, make me a better coder. That's why we are all here correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/azhzpLct/

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (document.querySelector('.code').value.match(/^[0-9]{6}\-[0-9]{6}\-[a-z]$/)) {
        alert('Sorry, you did not win.');
    }else{
        alert('Not a valid code. Please try again.')
    }
});
```

Comment: Would you recommend getting rid of the JQuery library to use this code? Also does anyone know of a good site that teaches JavaScripting? I feel that I've got a decent understanding on CSS and HTML, but am lacking in JavaScripting something fierce, and would like to take appropriate steps to correct this lack of knowledge.

Comment: After marking the adjustments in your JSFiddle, I am getting this error TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript, this is the best way of learning js. Can I see the adjustments?

Comment: You probable changed some classes name or changed dom structure so ```document.querySelector('form')``` or ```document.querySelector('.code')``` now is null, because can't find a node

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dark_nemesis/pvn29f1e/1/

The funny thing is, it works while in JSFiddle, but when I test the page in my browser on submitting the code, the page simply refreshes, and in the console, I get the above posted error

Comment: how do you use it in your browser? I think you just insert js before dom. Just insert it after, for example after body.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127964/discussion-between-dark-nemesis-and-sarkis-arutiunian).

Comment: Update: Thanks to Sarkis Arutiunian, I've discovered my error. I had my validation scripting all at the head of my document, and after moving it below my <body> element, it is working correctly. Thank you everyone for your willingness to help me!